# Comparação de dados Mysql de dois bancos diferentes - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Minha aplicação web deveria acessar dois bancos diferentes em diferentes servidores, colocar na tela a coluna dos dois bancos e comparar o resultado entre elas.

Porém, ele só retorna o valor de um dos bancos e o outro ele retorna tudo zero, conforme a imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($table_primal1) && $lineup = mysql_fetch_array($table_primal2) ) {

   $convert2 = (float) $line['campo016'];
   $convertup = (float) $lineup['campo016'];       
if($convertup==$convert2){
    $compara = 'Correto';
    $printtr = 'trcorrect';
    $printtd = 'correct';
} else {
    $compara = 'Erro';
    $printtr = 'trerror';
    $printtd = 'error';
}

   echo'<tr class='.$printtr.'>';
   echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$line['papel'].  '</td>';
   echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$line['campo036'].  '</td>';
   echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$convert2.  '</td>';
   echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$convertup.  '</td>';
   echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$compara.  '</td>';     
   echo'</tr>';
```

O código que devia fazer td isso é basicamente isso.
Tentei colocar um while dentro do outro, mas ele só me retorna o primeiro resultado da outra coluna e dps se repete.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue minhas Querys:

```
  $table_primal1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes where origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' ORDER BY papel ASC",$conexao_ori30a);

  $table_primal2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes where origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_8' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_7' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZS_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZC_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' or origem='30' and papel like 'ZL_9' AND campo012 >= '0' AND campo016 >='0' ORDER BY papel ASC", $conexao_ori30b);
```

Comment: Cade os seus `mysql_query()`?

Comment: Os `querys()` parecem certos, coloca também os `mysql_connect()`:P

Comment: Atualizei com elas

Comment: Essa conexão eu não posso mostrar, mas posso garantir que está funcionando perfeitamente, pois tinha conseguido imprimir as duas tabelas perfeitamente enquanto elas estavam separadas

Comment: Ok, quando vc chama o `mysql_connect()` informa 4 argumentos? sendo o último `true`? exemplo: `mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', true);`

Comment: Não, eu chamo o $login = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha') e dps chamo o mysql_select_db('banco', $login)

Comment: Passa `true` nas duas chamadas de `mysql_connect()`, deve resolver o problema. Imagino que o servidor, usuário e senha sejam os mesmos.

Comment: Conforme eu falei na pergunta, as tabelas estão em servidores distintos.
Dessa forma ainda funciona?

Comment: Mesmo passando o `true` não funcionou?

Comment: Eu mantenho o mysql_select_database né?

Comment: Sim, deixa `mysql_select_database` normal.

Comment: Ficou  a msm coisa do primeiro exemplo que eu dei :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei descobrindo a resposta sem querer kkk, vou postar aqui se eventualmente alguém tiver o mesmo problema.

Ao inves de colocar o $line_up= mysql_fetch_array($table_primal2) em algum while, eu simplesmente joguei ele junto com os valores que seriam obtidos pela tabela e deu certo.

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($table_primal1) ) {
    $line_up= mysql_fetch_array($table_primal2)

$convert2 = (float) $line['campo016'];
$convertup = (float) $lineup['campo016'];       
if($convertup==$convert2){
$compara = 'Correto';
$printtr = 'trcorrect';
$printtd = 'correct';
} else {
$compara = 'Erro';
$printtr = 'trerror';
$printtd = 'error';
}

echo'<tr class='.$printtr.'>';
echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$line['papel'].  '</td>';
echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$line['campo036'].  '</td>';
echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$convert2.  '</td>';
echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$convertup.  '</td>';
echo'<td class='.$printtd.'>'  .$compara.  '</td>';     
echo'</tr>';
```